# Javascript code works, but "not defined" warning in Firebug

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript code below, it's working but within Firebug it says

> document.form1.element[i] is not defined

and then it works fine

```
function set_action(){

for (var i=0;i<=3;i++)
{

    if (document.form1.PayType[i].checked == true)

        {
            var billerid = document.form1.billerid[i].value;
                            document.form1.action = billerid +"_mypag.htm";
        }
}
```

and my html markup is as below

```
<form name="form1" action="...">
<input name="PayType" type="radio" value="0" id="ultipay" class="radiobtn" checked/>
<select name="billerid" class="dropbox">
<option>item1</Option>...
</select>
<input name="PayType" type="radio" value="1" id="ultipay" class="radiobtn"/>
<select name="billerid" class="dropbox">
<option>item1</Option>
</select>
<input name="PayType" type="radio" value="2" id="ultipay" class="radiobtn"/>
<select name="billerid" class="dropbox">
<option>item1</Option>...
</select>
<input name="PayType" type="radio" value="3" id="ultipay" class="radiobtn"/>
<select name="billerid" class="dropbox">
<option>item1</Option>...
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="set_action()" value="submit">
</form>
```

I don't know why I am getting this error.

Comment: change form 1 to form in both hml and js ..then check

Comment: no, why should he do that? thats the name of his form!

Comment: You only have 4 elements, but iterate 7 (or, even worse, 8 - thanks @Marcel) of them?

Comment: i have proper code but for reference i have given part of it

Comment: @Bergi: 8, not 7 (`i<=7`)

Comment: post your full html and code..

Comment: You should be using `document.getElementById`, not `document.form.xxx`.

Comment: Since you have Firebug, have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code? For what value of i is the error occurring?

Comment: @Dancrumb...Bravo checked through breakpoints and got the error it just need the return type true. thanks a lot guys:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only **one** radio button named `PayType`, then you need to address it with `document.form1.PayType`. It is addressed as an array `document.form1.PayType[i]` iff there are multiple radio buttons with the same name. For instance:

```
<input name="PayType" type="radio" value="0" id="ultipay0" class="radiobtn" checked="checked" />
<input name="PayType" type="radio" value="1" id="ultipay1" class="radiobtn" />
```